# Displaying PostgGIS geometry on GeoDjango map widget?

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to display a custom map feature on a GeoDjango map. The geometry is a multipolygon stored in a PostGIS database backend.

And I have trouble to find the correct piece of documentation that explains how to load and add my geometry from the database. This is what my PostGIS contains:

```
SELECT * FROM aptroomat_worldborder;
```

[image: postgis table]

This is my `model.py` equivalent in my GeoDjango project:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class WorldBorder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is how I define my form in `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms

class WorldBorderForm(forms.Form):
    world = forms.MultiPolygonField(widget = 
        forms.OSMWidget(attrs = {'map_width': 1024, 'map_height': 600}))
```

And my `views.py` containing the callback:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myproject.forms import WorldBorderForm

def index(request):
    form = WorldBorderForm()
    context = { 'form': form }
    return render(request, 'myproject/index.html', context)
```

This is how the result looks including my template, using an OSM base widget:

[image: empty osm map]

This is pretty much what I get from reading the [GeoDjango documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/) and following the [GeoDjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) on World Borders.

But the missing piece in the docs is: How to display my geometries from the PostGIS database in my GeoDjango map widget? I can't seem to figure out how to connect both.

Any ideas?

Source code is on [github.com/donSchoe/sabracta](https://github.com/donSchoe/sabracta).

Versions used in this project are:

- python 3.4.3
- postgresql 9.4.1
- postgis 2.1.5
- django 1.7.4

Comment: This is a random guess, but have you tried the `OpenLayersWidget` instead of the `OSMWidget`. From the docs it seems that the one you are using is just for adding a map with a base layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display your shapefiles on the map canvas, it can be done by creating .kml files.

First in models.py create functions to convert data to .kml:

```
def shpPoint(request):
  points = ShapefilePoint.objects.kml()
  return render_to_kml("placemarks.kml", {'places': points})
```

placemarks.kml is a simple template for that purpose, it can be found in geodjango documentation I guess:

```
{% extends "base.kml" %}
{% block placemarks %}{% for place in places %}
  <Placemark>
    <name>{% if place.name %}{{ place.name }}{% else %}{{ place }}{% endif %}</name>
    <description>{% if place.description %}{{ place.description }}{% else %}{{ place }}{% endif %}</description>
    {{ place.kml|safe }}
  </Placemark>{% endfor %}{% endblock %}
```

and function to rendering:

```
def index(request):
  return render_to_response("map.html")
```

Now map your kml link in urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^point/', shpPoint),
...
```

And finally you can add your layer in JS code (this code contains example styling for point layer):

```
var PointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'Point',
    source: new ol.source.KML({
        projection:new ol.proj.get("EPSG:3857"),
    url:'http://localhost:8000/point/',
    extractStyles: false
    }),
  style: (function() {
  var textStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'yellow',
    width: 3
  });
  var textFill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'black'
  });
  return function(feature, resolution) {
    return [new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'yellow'}),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red'})
    }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '11px arial,sans-serif',
        text: feature.get('name'),
        fill: textFill,
        stroke: textStroke,
        offsetX: 25,
        offsetY: -10
      })
    })];
  };
})()

});
map.addLayer(PointLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/geodjango-maps-with-leaflet.html) using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) instead of OpenLayers. It worked for me and the docs and plugins are great. The GeoDjango tutorial does fall short for displaying maps.